# How to get content type and content disposition of attachment using CGI

Tags: python-3.x

```
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
print ("Content-type: text/html")
print("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=work_order-20240201.xlsx")
arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()
print(arguments)
```

Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; name="work_order-20240201.xlsx"

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="work_order-20240201.xlsx"

I am unable to get the arguments. Above two are my content type and content disposition. How to set header for these two